# Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'window' of undefined]

Tags: visualforce, aura, iframe

I am running into a very strange error.

I have an aura component that loads a visualforce page via iframe.

The iframe uses a post message to communicate with the aura component.

I have an event listener setup

```
window.addEventListener('message', $A.getCallback(function (event) {
            if (event.path) {
                if (event.path[0].window.location.origin != window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname) {
                    return;
                }

                //processing logic
            }
        }), false);
```

But I am getting an error Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'window' of undefined] on this the condition

```
if (event.path[0].window.location.origin != window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname) {
                    return;
                }
```

The same code is working properly as expected in Dev org/Scratch orgs, but when I test this in one of the sandboxes(installed as managed package) I am running into an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure why you get the error and I guess I'll wait for someone to answer. If you want get the origin URL from event, I believe you can use `event.origin` directly.

Comment: The Locker Service prevents cross-namespace access, and that means there is manipulation of the window global object, so I wonder if this could be part of the problem.

Comment: BTW if possible you should probably consider using the Lightning Message Service instead.

Comment: I cannot use Lightning Message Service - Since it inside iframe and that is not supported

Comment: At this moment I have changed the implementation and implementing all the logic from VF to LWC